# Mutilpe JS file included in another js file sometimes not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found how to include multiple js file into another js file but 1 problem i am facing is that this function is sometimes loaded and sometimes not, therefore sometimes the request goes directly to the server for server side validation without performing the client side validation.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
$.when(
        $.getScript('../../public/js/jquery.validate.min.js'),
        $.getScript('../../public/js/additional-methods.min.js'),
        $.Deferred(function(deferred) {
            $(deferred.resolve);
        })
        ).done(function() {

    $(function() {

        $("#login").validate({
            errorClass: "state-error",
            validClass: "state-success",
            errorElement: "em",
            rules: {
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                    minlength: 6,
                    maxlength: 50
                },
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6
                }
            },
            messages: {
                email: {
                    required: 'Enter your Email ID',
                    email: 'Enter a VALID Email ID',
                    minlength: 'Enter a VALID Email ID',
                    maxlength: 'Email ID can not be more than 50 characters'
                },
                password: {
                    required: 'Enter your Password',
                    minlength: 'Password must be minimum of 6 characters'
                }
            },
            highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                $(element).closest('.field').addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
            },
            unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                $(element).closest('.field').removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of your code sample, it seems what is happening is that the code files are being loaded after you try and submit. 
Several solutions you can do is to copy and paste the code from the other files so it executes and is read before your anonymous function starts, so that the function is available for client side validation. Another solution is to just put them all in order on the page and load them that way. The last solution, is to disable the submit button until the function is ready.
However, from this small snippet, it doesn't look like you need to load them into this one javascript file at all. Don't be afraid to have multiple js files on the page.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you probably want to use a proper module loader...

The two big popular module formats for Javascript are AMD ([Require JS](http://requirejs.org/)) and CommonJS ([modules for it](http://blog.brianbeck.com/post/10667967423/node-js-require-in-the-browser))

I'd suggest requireJS, since it's generally better for the browser since it's asynchronous.